# error: cannot find symbol method silentSignIn()

Tags: android-studio

i follow step on https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth

```
GoogleSignIn.silentSignIn()
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<GoogleSignInAccount>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task) {
                handleSignInResult(task);
            }
        });
```

but i get **error: cannot find symbol method silentSignIn()** 
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Same here, did you solve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe it was written on the docs this way by mistake.

1- The method `silentSignIn` is not static.

2- The `silentSignIn` is a method of the `GoogleSignInClient` class.

So the right way to invoke it, is:

```
GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient (activity, gso);

googleSignInClient.silentSignIn ()
    .addOnCompleteListener (activity, new OnCompleteListener<GoogleSignInAccount> () {

        @Override
        public void onComplete (@NonNull Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task) {
            handleSignInResult (task);
        }
    });
```